# Automatic content transform not wanted when using QNetworkAccessManager::get()

Tags: c++, qt4

When using the well known QNetworkAccessManager class for download a foo.tar.gz file from a web site, I got this file in my local dir, but in fact the content of the local file foo.tar.gz is foo.tar !
The file seems to be downloaded then unziped then written in foo.tar.gz

The same download with foo.zip or what so ever file works well...

I suspect mime automatic transform, could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

found !!!

For an unknown reason the linux QT version of this code :

```
 QNetworkRequest request(url);
 QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
```

add in object request something like :

```
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
```

the Mac OSX and Windows does not !! and when you try to download a foo.tar.gz file, the Linux version unzip (on the fly) the local file

May be a Qt4.7.1 bug ?!